# How would i wrap each image I added with jQuery with a link also

Tags: jquery

With some help , i was able to replace some text with an image for each member

```
$( "#chatscroll" ).html( $( "#chatscroll" ).html().replace('Fighting Moose Knuckles', '<img src="http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Moose_Icon.png" />') );

$( "#chatscroll" ).html( $( "#chatscroll" ).html().replace('Grundle Goblins', '<img src="http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Goblins_Icon.png" />') );

$( "#chatscroll" ).html( $( "#chatscroll" ).html().replace('Commissioner', '<img src="http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Commish_Icon.png" />') );
```

I need to add a link to each image to direct them to their profile page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just add the links to your existing code? See the `<a href="#">` in the example below:

```
$( "#chatscroll" ).html( $( "#chatscroll" ).html().replace('Fighting Moose Knuckles', '<a href="#"><img src="http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Moose_Icon.png" /></a>') );

$( "#chatscroll" ).html( $( "#chatscroll" ).html().replace('Grundle Goblins', '<a href="#"><img src="http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Goblins_Icon.png" /></a>') );

$( "#chatscroll" ).html( $( "#chatscroll" ).html().replace('Commissioner', '<a href="#"><img src="http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Commish_Icon.png" /></a>') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) at this context,

```
$('#chatscroll img').wrap('<a href="yourLink.com"></a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about introducing a bit of reusability.

```
function replaceTextWithImage($element, str, imageSrc){
    $element.html($element.html()
                  .replace(str, '<a href="#"><img src="'+ imageSrc +'"></a>'));
}

var $chatScroll = $("#chatscroll");
replaceTextWithImage($chatScroll, 'Fighting Moose Knuckles','http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Moose_Icon.png');
replaceTextWithImage($chatScroll, 'Grundle Goblins','http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Goblins_Icon.png');
replaceTextWithImage($chatScroll, 'Commissioner','http://larryvasta.com/football/img/icons/Commish_Icon.png');
```